# Trying to add simple notification.... not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

When I launch the page, I fire up the chrome dev tools and look in the sources window, load my file and I see

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoNotification is not a function
```

Im trying to modify an existing application ive been given which uses Kendo UI.  I just want to add in a notification popup.

Referring to the [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-common-issues), a common cause of this is not including all required javascript resources, but they all seem to be there.  jquery, kendo.all.min and were also using kendo.modernizr

Its obviously its my problem, since all the other kendo widgets work fine.

Im trying to follow this example
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-application-notifications-with-kendo-ui-core--cms-20989

Something is getting initialized correctly, im just not sure where/what it could be.

The page itself is rather large, but the notification is just

```
         <span id="popupNotification"></span>

        ... more html 



            <script>

            ....more stuff 


        $.ajax({

 ...

            success: function (result) {


                var popupNotification = $('#popupNotification').kendoNotification({
                    appendTo: "#SalesGrid", autoHideAfter: 5000, width: 400
                }).data('kendoNotification');


                var d = new Date();
                popupNotification.show({ time: kendo.toString(d, 'HH:MM:ss.') + kendo.toString(d.getMilliseconds(), "000") }, "time");


                }
    })    
            </script>
```

**[update]**
I just realized i was trying to show the notification from within an ajax call, so I found a more relevant example [here](http://jwcooney.com/2014/08/06/example-of-binding-a-kendo-ui-kendonotification-control-with-an-asp-net-webmethod/).

**[update 2, full source of function being called ]**

function postBatch(e) {

```
//alert('made it');
$.ajax({
    url: '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("SalesAction", "SalesController"))',
    data: { batchID: e, status: "POSTED" },
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        var statementBatchDS = $('#SalesGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource;
        statementBatchDS.data(result.Data);

        // *** FAILS HERE ***  note:  SalesGrid is a KendoUI grid 
        var popupNotification = $('#popupNotification').kendoNotification({
            appendTo: "#SalesGrid", autoHideAfter: 5000, width: 400
        }).data('kendoNotification');


        var d = new Date();
        popupNotification.show('Batch post error, please review', 'error');


        }
});
```

}

Where/which script source within Kendo UI is the KendoNotificaiton widget defined? Im using kendo.all.min.js, so I was assuming that included everything. Yet, when I call the notificaiton show method (see above), the error seems to indicate it cant construct the notification..which leads me to think the source isnt being included, yet the kendo.all.min.js file is clearly being pulled in as I inspect the source in Chrome's dev tools.

So off to Telerik I go, and I read these
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/scripts-general

Yet, the "all" version is whats in the reference
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/notification/index

Comment: Kindly show your full HTML code. Are there any other issues in Console?

Comment: Works here BTW: http://output.jsbin.com/zokev/2/?html,css,js,output

Comment: Ah-ha, I just realized Im trying to call the popup show method from within an ajax call, so that might need a different approach.

Comment: Yup.. Unless you give a full code, we can't help. Sorry.

Comment: In the success condition, just give the contents of the function.

Comment: Ive update the code snippet above and changed it around a few times trying different examples.

Comment: The last one seems working. What's happening with the code?

Comment: At the point of defining the popupnotification, the code errors, and breaks in jquery with an error of "TypeError: $(...).kendoNotification is not a function at Object.$.ajax.success..."  - it almost seems as if the kendonotification itself isnt reachable or in scope?

Comment: Seriously man, my point stands. **Kindly show your full HTML code.** Unless you show it, no one will be able to help. Good luck.

Comment: updates added to show full source of function being called

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and solved removing the kendo call from inside the AJAX snippet with a function:

```js
  success: function(data){
notify();// here i call a function to send the notification
clean();//another function to clear form data.
  },
  
...

function notify(){
  var popupNotification = $("#popupNotification").kendoNotification().data("kendoNotification");
  popupNotification.show("Some notification", "success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just a matter of upgrading the version of the Kendo libraries I was using.  At least im past the point of the Notification widget not being loaded.